# Url to archive page for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I made a custom post type , and an archive page for the post type. I don't know if there is a url where I can access this archive page? I would like to have a page where all the "posts" (products) for this archive is listed. But they don't need to be organized into post dates (what month and day).

Here is the code

```
function register_products_post_type() {
    $labels_array = [
        'name'  =>  __( 'Produkter', 'Divi' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Produkt', 'post type singular name', 'Divi' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Products', 'admin menu', 'Divi' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Product', 'add new on admin bar', 'Divi' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'product', 'Divi' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product', 'Divi' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Product', 'Divi' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product', 'Divi' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Product', 'Divi' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Products', 'Divi' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products', 'Divi' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Products:', 'Divi' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No products found.', 'Divi' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in Trash.', 'Divi' )

    ];

    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'labels'  => $labels_array,
        'description'        => __( 'beskrivning.', 'Divi' ),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'products', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_products_post_type' );
```

I have an archive.php and an archive-products.php. So the main thing I need is a url to the archive page for the post type. Then I need to edit that archive to display the products.

**edit**: when I try to access the page "/products" I reach a 404 page.

Another way I suppose would be to create a normal custom page where I would list the products, and use it as an "archive". I don't know if that would be the better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, before you do anything, make sure that you have flushed your permalinks, a 404 usually is a hint that you did not flush your permalinks after you created your custom post type the first time around.

[`get_post_type_archive_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) will return the URL to the post type archive page, so you would do the following

```
echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'products' );
```

to get the correct URL

As for a custom template, you can create an archive template called `archive-products.php` to display your products on. WordPress will automatically pick that template up and use it when you visit the products archive page